# Execution of conditional statement (v-if and v-else)

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am new to vue.js! And I am trying to learn from a course of Udemy. And I was trying some basic conditional statement as if-else statement. I followed all the instruction the course teacher have taught. I wrote the exam same code like him. But my code is compiling both if and else condition. Here I am adding my code:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>If-Else</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.6.11/vue.min.js">

    </script>
        </head>
        <body>
            <div id="app">
                <p v-if="rainy">The weather is rainy</p>
                <p v-else>The weather is sunny</p> 
            </div>
        </body>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        new vue({
            el: '#app',
            data: {
                rainy: false
            }
        });
        </script>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a typo, Vue is defined with first letter uppercase, and you should use it this way:

```js
new Vue({
  // ...
})
```

If you open the Console (F12 or ctrl+shift+i), you will see this error:

> ReferenceError: vue is not defined

JavaScript is case-sensitive, you should have caution with variable names.

Answer (score 1):

You should define data as a function in Vue.js. Also, use Vue instead of vue.

```js
new Vue({
        el: '#app',
        data: function() {
            return {
               rainy: false
            }
        }
    });
```